# Зачем нужен статический метод?

Tags: java

Знаю, что переменные static как бы общие для всех классов и являются единственным экземпляром.
Но зачем нам нужны статические методы ?
И почему мы не можем вызывать не-статические поля в статический методах

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static 
>        field

И в принципе не пойму в каких случаях использовать статические ?!

Comment: Разве в учебнике по яве это не объясняется с примерами?

Comment: @Эникейщик, думаю наоборот, читают литературу без самостоятельной практики написания кода. Отсюда не возникает ситуаций, когда, например, нельзя обойтись без того же статического метода и человеку непонятно зачем он нужен.

Comment: Ваши формулировки говорят о том, что вы плохо понимаете суть классов.  **переменные static общие для всех классов**  -- это неверно. **являются единственным экземпляром** -- это выражение лишено смысла. Разбирайтесь тщательнее, что такое класс, и что такое экземпляр класса aka объект. Если читаете учебник, читайте более вдумчиво или попробуйте почитать другой. Пробуйте писать, компилировать и выполнять примеры из учебника, пробуйте их менять, смотрите, что получается и старайтесь понять, почему.

Answer (score 1):

Статические переменные и методы принадлежат не конкретным объектам класса, а самому классу. Именно поэтому нельзя вызвать из статического метода (не привязанного к конкретному объекту) не-статический метод.

Comment: Как раз это разрешается, только корректнее будет использовать префикс класса перед вызовом.